# Convert a c hex value into a char*

Tags: c, char, hex

How to convert a `hex` value in c into an equivalent `char*` value. For example if the hex value is `1df2` the char* should also contain `1df2`.

I am using the `VinC` compiler and the `VinL` linker for the `VNC2 USB Chip` from `FTDI`. It has these following header files; **stdlib**, **stdio** and **string**. These are however subsets of the main c libraries and don't have the obvious answers such as `snprintf` or `sprintf`.

The docs say the following types are valid,

There are certain definitions for variable and function types which are used  throughout the kernel and drivers. They are available to applications in the `vos.h` header file.

Null pointer and logic definitions:

```
#define NULL                0
#define TRUE                1
#define FALSE               0
```

Variable type definitions:

```
#define uint8               unsigned char
#define int8                char
#define int16               short
#define uint16              unsigned short
#define uint32              unsigned int
#define pvoid               unsigned char *
```

Function type definitions:

```
typedef uint8 (*PF)(uint8);
typedef void (*PF_OPEN)(void *);
typedef void (*PF_CLOSE)(void *);
typedef uint8 (*PF_IOCTL)(pvoid);
typedef uint8 (*PF_IO)(uint8 *, unsigned short, unsigned short *);
typedef void (*PF_INT)(void);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot have "a char* with '1df2' in it", because there is nothing "in" the char*. Pointers don't contain data, they point to it. There is **no** real string type in C.

Comment: Just one of my peeves... if you mean convert a hex value into **a string**, then say it. Don't say "into a `char *`". A `char *` can be used to point to a string, but it's not a string.

Comment: Ok well I want to convert it to a string then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `snprintf()`:

```
int to_hex(char *output, size_t len, unsigned n)
{    
    return snprintf(output, len, "%.4x", n);
}
```

---

Given the new information that it's a fairly basic embedded system, then if you're only interested in 16 bit numbers a minimal solution like this probably suffices:

```
/* output points to buffer of at least 5 chars */
void to_hex_16(char *output, unsigned n)
{
    static const char hex_digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";

    output[0] = hex_digits[(n >> 12) & 0xf];
    output[1] = hex_digits[(n >> 8) & 0xf];
    output[2] = hex_digits[(n >> 4) & 0xf];
    output[3] = hex_digits[n & 0xf];
    output[4] = '\0';
}
```

(It should be clear how to extend it to wider numbers).

Comment: I dont have access to that function because I am developing on an embedded device! Any others ways?

Comment: It doesnt compile with unsigned n:[VinC.exe] : src\log.h line 5: (error) C2807 illegal function pointer declaration

Comment: @RenegadeAndy: If it doesn't accept the `unsigned` type then it is not actually a C compiler at all.  However, you can replace that with `unsigned int n`, since that is the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Try [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/):

```
int to_hex(char *output,unsigned n)
{    
    return sprintf(output, "%.4x", n);
}
```

it's less safe than caf's answer but should work if you have stdio. You *must* therefore make sure that the output buffer is big enough to hold the resulting string.

Comment: It infact has a subset of stdio so doesnt have sprintf either

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
void to_hex(char *buffer, size_t size, unsigned n)
{
    size_t i;
    size_t j;
    char c;
    unsigned digit;

    // Print digits in the reverse order
    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i)
    {
        digit = n & 0xf;
        buffer[i] = digit < 10 ? digit + '0' : digit - 10 + 'A';
        n >>= 4;

        if (n == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Append NUL
    buffer[i + 1] = 0;

    // Reverse the string
    for (j = 0; j < i / 2; ++j)
    {
        c = buffer[j];
        buffer[j] = buffer[i - j];
        buffer[i - j] = c;
    }
}
```

But you are saying you have `stdio` available, so there's no need write anything like this yourself.

**Edit:**  Could be that the compiler expects K&R style prototype:

```
void to_hex(buffer, size, n)
    char *buffer;
    size_t size; 
    unsigned n;
{
...
```

Try this on [Codepad](http://codepad.org/dGmnTULk).

Comment: This looks like the kind of solution im going to need. However it doesnt understand unsigned n, nor does it like unsigned void n - i think we have to give it a proper type....

Comment: How can it be that it doesn't understand `unsigned` type?  And there's no `unsigned void n` in this code.  Are you sure you don't have any strange macro definitions screwing this up?

Comment: No idea about macros... compiler states: [VinC.exe] : src\log.h line 5: (error) C2807 illegal function pointer declaration

Comment: I didn't realize that this was tagged as `C`.  I edited to make it `C` friendly.  Does it work now?  Still the errors the compiler produces are quite strange.

Comment: Im sorry I dont see what has changed..it wont compile with unsigned n

Comment: I moved variable declarations to the top.  I don't know why `unsigned` would not compile for any other reason except for macros.  Do you have any strange `#defines` in the code?

Comment: no...Is there no alternative..the docs say the compiler error means :  Error Description: illegal function pointer declaration

A function pointer was declared without the name of the function being made a pointer.

Example

int (PF)(int x, int y); //error illegal function pointer declaration

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see any function pointers declared here.  This code compiles just fine with Visual C compiler.

Comment: See my edit.  It could that the compiler expects K&R style parameters.